# instant app - feature module with could firestore error Default FirebaseApp is not initialised in this process

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, android-instant-apps

- When I am implement fire-base with my application at that time I am getting error like "Default Firebase is not intialized".
- In application module works well but issue with instant app its crash and show below error.

> Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process. Make sure to
>   call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

My Android Code, Dependency, Modules ::

```
**gradle file feature module(base-product).**

apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    baseFeature true
}
dependencies {
}

**module:instantapp gradle file is:**

    apply plugin: 'com.android.instantapp'
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':base-product')
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

**app: gradle**

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        }
    }
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

**module:Java file in First line :**

```
      FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(cId).document(dId).
                addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot qs, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                        if (qs.exists()) ... });
```

- Added Json file with 2 package name for same fire-base database  in base module as well application module.

> Below is my stack trace ::

```
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.zobaze.base.product. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(SourceFile:218)
            at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(SourceFile:49)
            at com.zobaze.base.product.ItemListActivity.onCreate(ItemListActivity.java:53)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Comment: So have you tried to initialize it first? Please also add the code that produces this error.

Comment: FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(cId).document(dId)
                    addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot qs, FirebaseFirestoreException e) { } . at first line

Comment: Can you please add the code as it is in your activity by editing the question (not as a comment).

Comment: does your base module also have `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` ?

Comment: and where is your `FirebaseApp.getInstance`, which module's source?

Comment: @TWL apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' add to base-feture working  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you have application class in feature - add `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)` in onCreate method.

this has happened because firebase plugin does not do it in automatic (as in application)